# Linear regression with convex combination of the parameters

Tags: optimization, least-squares, convex

I am looking for a method to solve the following linear regression problem:

$$
y_i=\sum_{j=1}^Kx_{ij}\beta_j+\varepsilon_i
$$

with all $\beta_j\geq0$ and $\sum \beta_j=1$. I am familiar with implementing the last restriction (substitute one of the $\beta_j$'s and solve with OLS), but I wouldn't know how to include the first restriction of nonnegative betas. Any help is welcome, as are heuristic methods in case a closed form/global optimum is not generally available.

Comment: This? [Analysing data measured as proportional composition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68944/analysing-data-measured-as-proportional-composition?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Or this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are more efficient methods to handle this problem but starting point could be to reparametrize it as
$$
y_i = \sum_{j}x_{ij}e^{\tau_j}.
$$

Having computed $\hat\tau_j$, the constrained estimates you are looking for are simply

$$\hat\beta_j = \log\tau_j.$$

To also handle the $\sum_j e^{\tau_j}=1$ constraint, the easiest way I can think of (from an implementation point of view) is to use the `nloptr` package of **R**.

See this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-a-constraint-optimization-problem-in-r-fdf5abee197b) for some examples on how to use `nloptr`.

Comment: That looks as if that deals with the $\beta_j>0$  though might hit problems if the optimum has a $\hat \beta_j=0$ i.e. $\tau_j=-\infty$ and ignores the $\sum \beta_j=1$

Comment: see my updated answer. The problem of an infinite solution is pervasive and as far as I know, you can't do much.